# Column as a result of difference of two other columns

Tags: postgresql

I recently looked up for a query that returned unused numbers in a table with consecutive numbers. (Some may be deleted and re-used again.)

It shows me the results `pnr_from` number to `pnr_to` number. Now I want to add a "How many" coloumn.

Is it possible to add this coloumn by using the aliases of the other two? (see commented line)

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(pnr)+1,1)
    FROM pord
    WHERE pnr < p.pnr
    ) AS pnr_from,
     p.pnr - 1 AS pnr_to
--  (pnr_to - pnr_from) AS how_many <-------- ERROR: coloumn "pnr_to" doesn't exist
FROM pord p
WHERE p.pnr != 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM pord p2
    WHERE p2.pnr = p.pnr - 1
    )
    AND pnr > 300 AND pnr < 600
ORDER BY von
```

Do I have to add the complete query as a subselect in the first SELECT-clause or is there another way?

Comment: Sounds like this could be made much simpler by using the `lag()` function. Can you add some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: This seems possible, too. I will try it, but I will accept Bohemian's answer, as I don't know yet how much I will expand my SELECT. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a subquery:

```
SELECT pnr_from, pnr_to, pnr_to - pnr_from AS how_many
FROM (
    SELECT (
        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(pnr)+1,1)
        FROM pord
        WHERE pnr < p.pnr
        ) AS pnr_from,
         p.pnr - 1 AS pnr_to,
        von
    FROM pord p
    WHERE p.pnr != 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM pord p2
        WHERE p2.pnr = p.pnr - 1
        )
        AND pnr > 300 AND pnr < 600
) t
ORDER BY von
```

Note how you have to select the column you want to order by so it's visible to the outer query.

Comment: Remodified it for my database and it just works. Exactly what I needed! And a little embarrassed, because I couldn't do that myself. Thanks for that!